# Firebase database child reference

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Those rounds refers to the user ID(uid),
My question is how can I refer to a child of the **current user**
I tried a lot like forEach, orderByKey etc.., but I could'nt find a solution so anyone can help me?
(**Note: I'm a beginner**)

Comment: what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data like name and age of the current user

Comment: 1) "I tried a lot" -> Please edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces what you tried. It is much easier for us to help if we see what you've already done. 2) Why are you storing the accounts under a push ID? I'd recommend not calling `push()`, but instead directly use `firebase.database().ref('Accounts').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set(...)`.

Comment: Thank you Frank Van Puffelen it worked for me! But what if I want to push another data to existing child without affecting existing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the structure of the database to the following:

```
Accounts
   userId
      randomId
          age : 100
          name : peter
   userId
      randomId
          age : 120
          name : peterx
```

This way it will be easier to query, now you can do the following:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("Accounts");
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

ref.child(user.uid).on("value",(snapshot)=> {
 snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
  let childData = childSnapshot.val();
  let age = childData.age;
  let name = childData.name;
  console.log(childData);
 });
});
```

Another way is to remove the randomId and directly access the data without using `forEach`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: But when I try to log name and age it shows me undefined

Comment: where are u logging?

Comment: after console.log(childData) I tried console.log(`${age} and ${name}`)

Comment: what does `console.log(childData);` give you? Also the api is asynchronous so you can only access the data inside the foreach